# How to install Jahshaka?

Tags: software-installation

I found that there is an application called Jahshaka which is used to edit videos. I want to install it in my Ubuntu. How to install it? I can't find it in Software center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Jahshaka [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/Jahshaka%202.0/download) and put the file in a folder of your choice, e.g. `~/MyApps`

Then follow these steps:

```
cd ~/MyApps
mv Jahshaka\ 2.0 jahshaka_2-0
chmod +x jahshaka_2-0
```

It may be that you still need the following libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse2:i386
sudo apt-get install libxmu6:i386
sudo apt-get install libxft2:i386
```

The start Jahshaka with:

```
~/MyApps/jahshaka_2-0
```

For a better integration with your desktop, you can create a `.desktop` file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/jahshaka.desktop
```

and paste these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Jahshaka
Comment=video and film compositing, editing and special fx system
Icon=/path/to/image
Exec=/home/<your_username>/MyApps/jahshaka_2-0
Terminal=false
Categories=Video;
StartupWMClass=Jahshaka
```

Then save and exit...

Answer (score 0):

Jahshaka support for Ubuntu appears to be very, very shaky. Your best chances are to download the portable version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portable/files/Jahshaka%202.0/download), make it executable (`chmod`) and hope for the best.

Comment: I asked to know how to install that portable file I download from that website. Can you tell me how please?

Comment: There is no install procedure. From the terminal, go to the Downloads folder (`cd ~/Downloads`), make the file executable (`chmod +x Jahshaka\ 2.0`) and run it (`./Jahshaka\ 2.0`).